# Kicked out of JIRA when using API

Tags: ios, api, rest, jira, basic-authentication

I'm using the JIRA REST api in an IOS app I'm building.

Every time I connect to the API using basic authentication with my credentials I'm kicked out of JIRA on my desktop.

Any ideas how I can stop this.

JIRA happily lets me log in using more than 1 client, it's only when I use the api through my app that it kicks me out.

Comment: Did you try JIRA's support page? https://www.atlassian.com/resources/support Chances are they'll know better how to help.

Comment: Reported to JIRA. They said report on answers.atlassian. Reported on that .. still no answers. Humph guess I'll have to fix this the old fashioned way. Actually do some work.